# Consistent bar width in ggplot barplot for vectors with unequal length in same dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe

Being new to r i've encountered a problem. I have a 44 row dataframe with 3 variables as the one in the below example:

```
> df

    Var_A     Var_B    Var_C
[1]  AA        20      Cat_1
[2]  AA        85      Cat_2
[3]  AB        65      Cat_1
[4]  AC        17      Cat_1
[5]  AC        69      Cat_2
[6]  AD        100     Cat_2
[7]  AE        100     Cat_2
...

> str(df)
'data.frame':   44 obs. of  3 variables:
$ Var_A       : Factor w/ 32 levels "AA","AB",..: 26 29 32 27 17 30 21 11 28 25 ...
..- attr(*, "scores")= num [1:32(1d)] 17429 5067 230 178 21663 ...
.. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
.. .. ..$ : chr  "AA" "AB" "AC" "AD" ...
$ Var_B       : num  20 85 65 17 69 ...
$ Var_C       : chr  "Cat_1 " "Cat_2 " "Cat_1 " "Cat_1 " ...

> dput(df[1:5,])
structure(list(Var_A = structure(c(26L, 29L, 32L, 27L, 
17L), .Label = c("AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", 
"AE", "AF", "AG", "AH", "AI", 
"AJ", "AK", "AL", "AM", "AN", 
"AO", "AP", "AQ", "AR", "AS", 
"AT", "AU", "AV", "AW", "AX", 
"AY", "AZ", "BA", "BB", "BC", "BD", 
"BE", "BF"), class = "factor"), Var_B = c(20, 
85, 65, 17, 69)), Var_C = c("Cat_1 ", 
"Cat_2 ", "Cat_1 ", "Cat_1 ", "Cat_2 "), .Names = c("Var_A", 
"Var_B", "Var_C"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

And I wish to barplot these 3 variables using ggplot2, but for those categories in Var_A which don't have one of the 2 categories in Var_C I get bars thicker than those who have both. I looked on other posts in order to fix this issue  and have bars of consistent width for Var_A despite lacking one of the 2 categories in Var_C, and tried out the following options:

Option # 1

```
 > all.df <- rbind(ddply(df,.(Var_A, Var_C), summarise, count = length(Var_C)), 
  c(Cat_1, Cat_2, NA))
```

but I obtain the following message:

```
Error in rbind(ddply(df, .(Var_A, Var_C), summarise, count = length(Var_C)),  : 
object 'Cat_1' not found
```

And Option # 2:

```
> all.df <- rbind(df, cbind(expand.grid(Var_A=levels(df$Var_A), Var_C=levels(df$Var_C)), 
Var_B=NA))
```

But also obtain the following message:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 
0, 1
```

Therefore I've looked on how to combining columns of equal row length, but all available answers described on how to do so for 2 dataframes, and not on a single dataframe. I've tried with rbind.fill and indexing but up to now I haven't managed to achieve the desired outcome.

I'm working in Rstudio Version 0.99.441, in Windows 7.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It may need further cleaning before processing. can you add `dput(df[1:5,])` please?

Comment: @plafort I included dput as requested, let me know in case of any other required information.

Comment: I'm getting errors with your dput code

Comment: Looks like you have minor errors in both your options.  In Option 1 you need to have quotes around the characters values, e.g., `"Cat_1"` (although I'm not sure this code will do you want it to do).  In Option 2, you try to use `levels` on a character variable, as `Var_C` is a character instead of a factor.  Characters don't have levels so `levels(df$Var_C)` returns `NULL`.  An alternative to `levels` is `unique`.

Comment: @aosmith, i'm getting the following message: **Option 1** `Error: unexpected '=' in "all.df <- rbind(ddply(df,.(df$Var_A,df$Var_C), summarise, df$Var_B ="` and for **Option 2** `Error: unexpected '=' in "all.df <- rbind(df, cbind(expand.grid(Var_A=levels(df$Var_A), Var_C=unique(df$Var_C)), df$Var_B="`.

Comment: That's because you changed `Var_B` to `df$Var_B` within `cbind` and `ddply`.

Comment: @ aosmith, now **Option 2** worked perfectly.